# Use Intl.NumberFormat without rounding

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I'm using `Intl.NumberFormat` to format numbers:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 1,
    maximumFractionDigits: 4,
    minimumSignificantDigits: 1,
    maximumSignificantDigits: 4
  })

formatter.format(0.99999) // results: '1'. desired result: '0.9999'
formatter.format(0.006393555) // results: '0.006394'. desired result: '0.006393'
formatter.format(0.9972620384752073) // results: '0.9973'. desired result: '0.9972'
formatter.format(12345.67) // results: '12,350'. desired result: '12,345.67'
formatter.format(200001) // results: '200,000'. desired result: '200,001'
```

As you can see the numbers are being rounded automatically, which is undesirable behavior in my case.

Is there a way to tell the formatter not to round?
I Didn't [found any option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) or combination of options to achieve that.

Comment: increase the `maximumSignificantDigits` to a number that will be 1 more than the number of decimals?

Comment: What is the desired result from a number like `12345.67`?

Comment: Expanding off of KIKO's question - is your use case only with fractional numbers (the only examples provided)? If you will be formatting values greater than 1, please update your question with some formatting cases with those.

Comment: In all cases fractional numbers should preserve their fractional digits up to 4 significant digits.
So  `12345.67` should result `12,345.67`.

Comment: @baba-dev updated my answer based on your latest changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with current spec and there are [few proposals for the new spec](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/ecma402/README.md), but you can still use `formatToParts` method and add custom function to format number parts as you wish.

For your first use case it could look something like:

```js
const trauncateFractionAndFormat = (parts, digits) => {
  return parts.map(({ type, value }) => {
    if (type !== 'fraction' || !value || value.length < digits) {
      return value;
    }
    
    let retVal = "";
    for (let idx = 0, counter = 0; idx < value.length && counter < digits; idx++) {
      if (value[idx] !== '0') {
        counter++;
      }
      retVal += value[idx];
    }
    return retVal;
  }).reduce((string, part) => string + part);
};
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumFractionDigits: 20
})

console.log(trauncateFractionAndFormat(formatter.formatToParts(0.99999), 4));
console.log(trauncateFractionAndFormat(formatter.formatToParts(0.006393555), 4));
console.log(trauncateFractionAndFormat(formatter.formatToParts(0.9972620384752073), 4));
console.log(trauncateFractionAndFormat(formatter.formatToParts(12345.67), 4));
console.log(trauncateFractionAndFormat(formatter.formatToParts(20001), 4));
```

Comment: This does not work for `20.00001`

Answer (score 3):

NumberFormat will always round up, but you can play around this one extra function.

```
function roundDownSignificantDigits(number, decimals) {
  let significantDigits = (parseInt(number.toExponential().split('e-')[1])) || 0;
  let decimalsUpdated = (decimals || 0) +  significantDigits - 1;
  decimals = Math.min(decimalsUpdated, number.toString().length);

  return (Math.floor(number * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals));
}
```

and then

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 1,
  maximumFractionDigits: 4,
  minimumSignificantDigits: 1,
  maximumSignificantDigits: 4
})
```

result:

```
formatter.format(roundDownSignificantDigits(0.99999,4)); // "0.9999"
formatter.format(roundDownSignificantDigits(0.006393555,4)); // "0.006393"
formatter.format(roundDownSignificantDigits(0.9972620384752073,4)); // "0.9972"
```

Comment: This will fail for the second test case `0.006393555` by resulting in `"0.0063"` _instead_ of `"0.006393"`

Comment: NumberFormat also round down... not just up. see the last example in my code.

Comment: @concision I update my function roundDownSignificantDigits, and now it should work just fine

Answer (score 2):

You need just to add roundingMode: 'floor';

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 1,
    maximumFractionDigits: 4,
    minimumSignificantDigits: 1,
    maximumSignificantDigits: 4,
    roundingMode: 'floor'
  })

formatter.format(0.99999) // results: '1'. desired result: '0.9999'
formatter.format(0.006393555) // results: '0.006394'. desired result: '0.006393'
formatter.format(0.9972620384752073) // results: '0.9973'. desired result: '0.9972'
formatter.format(12345.67) // results: '12,350'. desired result: '12,345.67'
formatter.format(200001) // results: '200,000'. desired result: '200,001'
```

Comment: As of June 2023 this is still experimental though and according to MDN no browser supports this yet https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the above solutions round off the value,
here is the simplest Solution I'm using and its working fine for me,

```
let a = "2.2652";// string
let b = 2.2652; // decimal-number
let c = 22200223.26522200225; // decimal-number
let d = 2 // non-decimal
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 20,
    minimumSignificantDigits: 1,
    maximumSignificantDigits: 20
  });



const newFunc = (val)=>{
  val = formatter.format((val))
  if(val.includes(".")){
    let number = val.toString().split(".")[0]+"."+val.split(".")[1].slice(0, 2)
  return number
  }else{
    return val
  }

}
console.log(newFunc(a))
console.log(newFunc(b))
console.log(newFunc(c))
console.log(newFunc(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get it using formatToParts. You can also do some javascript Array functions tricks to separate out the decimal part if needed.

```
export const formatNumberWithoutDecimals = (price) =>
  new Intl.NumberFormat(i18n.language, {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  }).formatToParts(price).reduce((result, part) => (part.type !== "decimal" && part.type !== "fraction") ? result + part.value : result, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up doing `toFixed(2)` first to get the right rounding, then converting to number then to string again with `toLocaleString`.

Something like this:

```js
const myNumber = 66483.385

// If I do
myNumber.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});
// It returns '66,483.39' which is wrong

// So I did this to get the right value:
Number(myNumber.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en-US');
// '66,483.38'
```